# Why does a finished python script still blocks memory?

Tags: memory, python, process, htop

I'm running a python3 script that is performing a lot of in-memory operations, thus using a lot of RAM. My machine has 256GB of RAM. I noticed, that even my script finishes (the program get's to the end of the steps in the `__main__` function), and all my results are saved in the file, the `htop` command still shows a huge RAM usage. Only running `pkill -9 -f myscript.py` cleans the memory. Why is that so? If my program finishes, shouldn't the memory automatically be free?

Comment: If it finishes, yes. You basically say it does not. You should find out why it doesn’t close. Maybe wait a little longer (a few hours) to see if it closes eventually.

Comment: @DanielB Can it have anything to do with a missing 'return' in a Python function? The function doesn't have to return anything, so I skipped it, but maybe this is blocking?

Comment: No. Most likely something is still running. Maybe you’re using threads? You’ll have to figure this out yourself. Thing is: Your script doesn’t terminate so that’s your problem. Once you can get it terminate, the memory it uses will be released properly.

Comment: @DanielB I'm using Pool from the multiprocessing module. When I look at the command line, it seems like the code is finished (there is no freezing or anything, the console output suggests everything is finished). Can it be, that although in the command line it looks like the script finished (i.e., the command line is ready for a new command) something, e.g., saving in a file, is still running? Or maybe the thing which is eating memory is actually some old python script which I stopped with CTRL+Z?